# Adding and deleting DOM objects within a DOM object

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a button named 'Add Detail'.

1. On clicking 'Add Detail' button, a record consisting of a textfield, a button named 'Details' and a button named 'Remove' is created (Using DOM).
2. On clicking the 'Remove' button, that particular record is deleted.
3. On clicking 'Details', a popup form appears consisting of two buttons namely 'Close' button (to close the popup form) and 'Add TextField' button.
4. On clicking the 'Add TextField' button in the popup form, a new textfield should be generated at every 'onclick' instance.

Now I have a minor problem here. The records (consisting textfield, 'Details' Button & 'Remove' Button) that I mentioned above are being generated on clicking the 'Add Detail' Button.

Also the particular record is deleted on clicking the 'Remove' button. Even on clicking the 'Details' button, the popup form is generated. And on clicking the 'Close' button (in popup form), the popup form is closed.

Now on clicking the 'Add TextField' button (in popup form), the textfields are added (using DOM). But when I close the popup form after adding textfields (using 'Add Textfield' button) in it and on reopening that popup form the textfields are not there that I added.

Basically the 'Add TextField' Button in the popup form is working only once. Even when I add a new record and click the details to generate a new popup form and click on 'Add TextField' button, no textfields are generated.

I feel I am missing something here. Below is the HTML and Javascript code for the following. Please excuse the length of the javascript code. Also please tell me if there is a better way of tackling this problem.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Add Plus Add Div</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="addText()">Add Detail</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code:

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function DivOpen() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
  };

  function DivClose() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "none";
  };

  var addTextArray = [];
  function addText() {
    var addTextIndex = addTextArray.length
    var a = document.createElement("input");
    a.type = "text";
    a.id = "text1" + addTextIndex;
    addTextArray.push(div2.appendChild(a));

    var c = document.createElement("button");
    c.type = "button";
    c.innerHTML = "Details";
    c.id = "DetailButton" + addTextIndex;
    c.setAttribute("onclick", "AddDetails1()");
    div2.appendChild(c);

    var b = document.createElement("button");
    b.type = "button";
    b.id = "RemoveButton" + addTextIndex;
    b.innerHTML = "Remove";
    b.setAttribute("onclick", "removeText("+addTextIndex+")");
    div2.appendChild(b);

    var d = document.createElement("br");
    d.id = "br1" + addTextIndex;
    div2.appendChild(d);
  };

  function removeText(addTextIndex) {
    var remText = document.getElementById('text1' + addTextIndex);
    remText.parentElement.removeChild(remText);
    var remButtonDet = document.getElementById('DetailButton' + addTextIndex);
    remButtonDet.parentElement.removeChild(remButtonDet);
    var remButtonRem = document.getElementById('RemoveButton' + addTextIndex);
    remButtonRem.parentElement.removeChild(remButtonRem);
    var remBr = document.getElementById('br1' + addTextIndex);
    remBr.parentElement.removeChild(remBr);
  };

  var AddDetails1Array = [];
  function AddDetails1() {
    var AddDetails1Index = AddDetails1Array.length;
    var a1 = document.createElement("div");
    a1.id = "PopUpDiv" + AddDetails1Index; 
    a1.style.position = "fixed";
    a1.style.display = "block";
    a1.style.width = "100%";
    a1.style.height = "100%";
    a1.style.top = "0";
    a1.style.left = "0";
    a1.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    a1.style.opacity = ".5";
    AddDetails1Array.push(document.body.appendChild(a1));

    var b = document.createElement("form");
    b.id = "innerForm";
    b.style.width = "500px";
    b.style.height = "200px";
    b.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    b.style.margin = "100px auto";
    b.style.border = "1px solid black";
    a1.appendChild(b);

    var c = document.createElement("button");
    c.type = "button";
    c.id = "buttonPopUpId";
    c.innerHTML = "Close";
    c.setAttribute("onclick", "ClosePopUp("+AddDetails1Index+")");
    b.appendChild(c);

    var d = document.createElement("button");
    d.type = "button";
    d.id = "AddTextInnerForm";
    d.innerHTML = "Add TextField";
    d.setAttribute("onclick", "AddTextField1()");
    b.appendChild(d);
  };

  function ClosePopUp(AddDetails1Index) {
    document.getElementById('PopUpDiv' + AddDetails1Index).style.display = "none";
  };

  function AddTextField1() {
    var a = document.createElement("input");
    a.type = "text";
    a.name = "text1";
    a.id = "text1Id";
    innerForm.appendChild(a);
  };

</script>
```

Comment: Just some comments. The *language* attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and removed in HTML 5, the *type* attribute is unnecessary. Variables starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructor functions.

Comment: how do you open the popup? I can only see the code to close it here. Maybe the problem is there

Comment: please provide working sample where you are facing issue. so that we can debug